# Scikit learn SGDClassifier: precision and recall change the values each time

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

I have a question about the precision and recall values in scikit learn. I am using the function `SGDClassifier` to classify my data. 
To evaluate the performances, I am using the precision and recall function `precision_recall_fscore_support` but each time that I run the program I have different values in the precision and recall matrix. How can I have the true values? 
My code is:

```
scalerI = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_train = scalerI.fit_transform(InputT)
X_test = scalerI.transform(InputCross)
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="elasticnet",n_iter=70)
y_rbf = clf.fit(X_train,TargetT)
y_hat=clf.predict(X_test)
a= clf.predict_proba(X_test)
p_and_rec=precision_recall_fscore_support(TargetCross,y_hat,beta=1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) SGDClassifier has a `random_state` param that is initialised to `None` this is a seed value used for the random number generator. You need to fix this value so the results are repeatable so set `random_state=0` or whatever favourite number you want

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="elasticnet",n_iter=70, random_state=0)
```

should produce the same results for each run

From the docs:

> random_state : int seed, RandomState instance, or None (default) The
>   seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when shuffling the
>   data.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't understand the meaning of the random state. So now the question could be how choose the best number to have the best results